# Jenkins pulling image from local registry: Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-registry

I am running a docker registry locally on my machine, and I can pull my image from it successfully:

```
docker pull 192.168.174.205:5001/myimg:latest
```

I am also running a jenkins container on my machine, but Jenkins cannot pull any image from the local registry. I use a Blue Ocean container (on the same machine) to start a pipeline, and it outputs:

```
+ docker pull 192.168.174.205:5001/insureio:latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.174.205:5001/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
script returned exit code 1
```

---

## TMI

**Specs**

- Docker version 1.13.1, build 4ef4b30/1.13.1
- Jenkins ver. 2.204.2
- host CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

**Reference**

I have been working from the instructions on

- https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/
- https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#custom-registry

**Settings**

My `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file reads `{"insecure-registries" : ["192.168.174.205:5001"]}`.

The local registry gives a 200 response:

```
curl http://192.168.174.205:5001/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["mying"]}
```

My pipeline script is:

```
node {
  stage('Build') {
    docker.withRegistry('http://192.168.174.205:5001') {
      docker.image('insureio:latest').inside('') {
        sh 'make test'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both Jenkins and your registry are containers, Jenkins is going to be looking at the 192.168.174.205 IP address at its own network space.

If you're just trying things out, I would suggest doing a `docker inspect <your registry container>  | grep -i ipaddress` to find its IP address (by default it should be in the region of 172.17.XXX.XXX) and configure your pipeline to use that address.

Comment: Thanks very much, but with that change, I get `Error response from daemon: Get https://172.17.0.2:5001/v2/: dial tcp 172.17.0.2:5001: connect: no route to host`. Do you have an idea what the matter might be?

Comment: I see it tries to do an `https` connection? A faster way to debug this would be to get a shell on your jenkins container, something like `docker exec -it <container_id> sh` and run various `curl` commands from within the container.